# Session Data is Remaining After Destroying Old Session

Tags: php, session, logout

```
session_start();
// Unset all of the session variables.
session_unset();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 420000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();

header("location: ../index.html");
die();`
```

My logout script is above:

The login system doesn't have any issues and when a user tries to logout after clearing their browser cache, the system works, but when different accounts are logged into one after another, it appears the session data is getting mixed up and not being cleared on logout. I got the code snippet off of the PHP manual. For the life of me, I cannot figure out what is wrong. I checked the Chrome cookie data and the PHPSSID is being deleted upon logout, which leads me to believe the session is being destroying.

To make it clear lets say John logs into website and logs out. Paul comes and logs into the website on the same computer and browser, but instead of Paul seeing his name when he logs in, he sees Johns. That's the issue I'm facing.

Thank you for any feedback.

I've tried using different scripts and tried unsetting the entire session using unset($_SESSION), but that made the problem worse. I also tried unsetting individual session variables such as unset($_SESSION['username']), but that didn't work either.

Comment: How are you calling this logout code? Are you sure it's being executed?

Comment: It's being called when a link in the navbar is being pressed. I believe its being executed because the cookie named "PHPSESSID" deletes once called (I'm viewing that through chrome dev tools). I temporarily solved the problem by turning on minimal caching in the hosts firewall settings, but I don't want that to be the forever solution. Does the code block look incorrect? Again, I pulled it straight from the PHP manual. The only thing I changed was instead of calling $_SESSION = array();, I did session_unset();. From what I heard they accomplish the same task.

Comment: A link, or an AJAX call? Logout code often fails in AJAX calls when the browser closes the page before the AJAX call actually clls the server. This looks very much like that.

Comment: It's not an ajax call. It's nested in a-tag <a class="dropdown-item" href="../../includes/logout.inc.php">Logout</a>. This could be the wrong way to do, but it's been like this for quite a while.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the code where the login happens

Are you sure a user is not automatically logged in based on a cookie being present and a session automatically created (if not present)?

I know you be going "ugggh..." but that could be the only logical explanation. It is a nasty insecure way of logging in users, but it could happen

Comment: The login script on includes me verifying user credentials using password_verify(); and the email by connecting to mysql using prepared statements. After its been verified, I call session_start();, set the session variables and use header(location: ...); exit(); to send them to the correct page. Is there another way i should be logging users in. I use godaddy as my host (i know gross), but when I changed the caching settings to site cache only it fixed the issue. I still want to know if there is anything wrong with my code.

Comment: Maybe it was an issue with the site cache. Talking of the provider you mention, I've never had good experiences with their tech support team (on behalf of a client), so it could be time consuming to get it from them. One of the good practices with session handling is that you do a https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php if you are frequently writing to it, from ajax, etc., once in each https call,  for example.